# Jupyter client browser window on iPad frequently disconnects from Jupyter server - how to resolve?

Tags: python, ios, ipad, jupyter

Is there any way to independently run Jupyter Notebook on iOS/iPad Pro, without remote connection? Chrome or safari allow for accessing the Jupyter Notebook browser version but the connection to the kernel is constantly disrupted.

If not, what are good python environments/apps for iPad Pro / iOS? Not a big fan of Pythonista as I use pandas which is not available in Pythonista.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I'm new to stackoverflow and submitted the above question which was now 'put on hold'? Why is that? All I'm asking if somebody knows how to make Jupyter Notebook work on the iPad...why would this be 'opinion-based'? I'm looking for help here, nothing else.

Comment: This shouldn't have been put on hold. Welcome to Stack Overflow - unfortunately there are high-ranking folks who take it upon themselves to yank down questions even when they're not in the field.  Indeed, disconnection from the Jupyter server from iPad is a real problem (I was just hunting around trying to find a solution/discussion of this, and ran into this question). I think if you rephrased the title to read 'Jupyter client browser window on iPad frequently disconnects from Jupyter server - how to resolve?' - it might pass the serial closevoters.  Important question, thanks for asking.

Comment: Thank you very much Dan! I'll follow your advise and rephrase the title.